# Angular 2 remove params from url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have `/users` page with list of users, I can click on Edit User button and see User details on this url `/users/edit/1`, when I save changes I want to highlight changed user. For that I use the following method:

```
gotoUsers(userId) {
    this.router.navigate(['../../', { id: userId }], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

And I see in url `/users;id=1` and changed user is highlighted.
If I want to edit other user again. And click on Edit button I see `/users;id=1/edit/2`

Click on Edit button:

```
gotoEditUser(userId: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['edit', userId], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

How can I remove `;id=1` param from url?

Comment: Have your tried `{ replaceUrl: true }` on `gotoEditUser` ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Because you use `relativeTo: this.route` in `gotoEditUser` the url starts from the current url witch is `/users;id=1`
you can see more information on this here: [Assume relative navigation are being performed relative to the current activated route](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9476)

Answer (score 1):

I've edited `gotoEditUser` method:

```
gotoEditUser(userId: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['../', 'users', 'edit', userId], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

But yet looking for the best solution for that.

Comment: They seemed to have solved it with query parameters via [`queryParamsHandling`](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) but not [matrix url notation](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional)